# Terraform 13, Validate variable base on the value of another

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is there a way of implementing the below logic

```
variable "environment" {
  description = "The environment this will be run in can only be set to [preprod|test|prod]"
  type        = string
  default     = "test"
  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^(prod|preprod|test)$", var.environment))
    error_message = "The environment variable can only be set to [prod|preprod|test]."
  }
}

variable "fet_code" {
  description = "Set the feature code"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
  validation {
    condition     = var.environment == "test" && length(var.fet_code) != 3
    error_message = "The environment has been set to 'test' but the fet_code has not be defined."
  }
}
```

At the moment i get the following error:

```
Error: Invalid reference in variable validation

  on variable.tf line 17, in variable "fet_code":
  17:     condition     = var.environment == "fet" && length(var.fet_code) == 3

The condition for variable "fet_code" can only refer to the variable itself,
using var.fet_code.
```

I understand what the problem is with the code, I am just wondering if there is a way round the restriction?

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve from that `fet_code` `condition`; could you clarify? Also why is there a check if the `environment` variable equals `feature` if that is not an allowed input value according to the `condition` on `environment`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard thanks pointing out the errors. I think i fixed all the issues.
The logic is I am trying to code is IF variable `environment` is set to `test` then variable `fet_code` has to be set else it should be blank

Comment: Ok so this is not possible because values of variables cannot be used inside variable declarations, but if it were you would use a ternary to control the `true`/`false` returns like: `var.environment == "test" ? (length(var.fet_code) == 3) : true`. Note also you switched the `true` / `false` return for the validation on the `fet_code` length. https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

While there's a [Github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25609) for implementing this as a feature, the only way to validate against multiple variables is by using locals to throw an error at runtime:

```
variable "environment" {
  description = "The environment this will be run in can only be set to [preprod|test|prod]"
  type        = string
  default     = "test"
  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^(prod|preprod|test)$", var.environment))
    error_message = "The environment variable can only be set to [prod|preprod|test]."
  }
}

variable "fet_code" {
  description = "Set the feature code"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

locals {
  validate_fet_code_cnd = var.environment == "test" && length(var.fet_code) != 3
  validate_fet_code_msg = "The environment has been set to 'test' but the fet_code has not been defined."
  validate_fet_code_chk = regex(
      "^${local.validate_fet_code_msg}$",
      ( !local.validate_fet_code_cnd
        ? local.validate_fet_code_msg
        : "" ) )
}
```

It's a messy, sketchy hack, but it should prevent invalid values from getting applied.

Comment: I think a cleaner solution was suggested in the above github issue just recently. take a look https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25609#issuecomment-1057614400

Comment: What part of "messy sketchy hack" was unclear? :P  My answer is only an _exact_ response to the question of how to validate against multiple _variables_. I don't recommend actually doing it. The _better_ option (for now) is to use the object variable method @martin-verner suggested.

Answer (score 16):

It seems to me that the two variables are close related. I would change them to one object in order to achieve what you want.

```
variable "environment" {
  type = object({
    environment = string
    fet_code = string
  })
  default = {
    environment = "test"
    fet_code = ""
  }

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^(prod|preprod|test)$", var.environment.environment))
    error_message = "The environment variable can only be set to [prod|preprod|test]."
  }

  validation {
    condition     = var.environment.environment == "test" && length(var.environment.fet_code) != 3
    error_message = "The environment has been set to 'test' but the fet_code has not be defined."
  }
}
```

You can then pass the variables like this:

```
environment = {
  environment = "test"
  fet_code = "1234"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I found for a similar problem for myself was to put the check in a module.
Said module is then only included if and when the environment requires the variable to be set.

```
module input_validation {
    source   = "./modules/input_validation"
    count    = var.environment == "test" ? 1 : 0
    fet_code = var.fet_code
}
```

And then in modules/input_validation/input_validation.tf:

```
variable "fet_code" {
  default = ""
  type    = string
  validation {
    condition     = length(var.fet_code) != 3
    error_message = "The environment has been set to 'test' but the fet_code has not be defined."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be utilising [preconditions](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/custom-conditions#preconditions-and-postconditions) which is available in Terraform v1.2.0 and later. It can be set in `lifecycle` block inside `resource`, `data`, `output` and `source`.

```
variable "environment" {
  description = "The environment this will be run in can only be set to [preprod|test|prod]"
  type        = string
  default     = "test"
  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^(prod|preprod|test)$", var.environment))
    error_message = "The environment variable can only be set to [prod|preprod|test]."
  }
}

variable "fet_code" {
  description = "Set the feature code"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

resource "resource" "example" {
  attribute = "value"

  lifecycle {
    precondition {
      condition     = var.environment == "test" && length(var.fet_code) != 3
      error_message = "The environment has been set to 'test' but the fet_code has not be defined."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comment @Torge, as you mention working with a local source module, is possible to validate multiple variables or locals

As example in source code define some locals that can take hardcoded values or from variables input. Validation of clauses are resolved by boolean local `consolidation`

```
locals {
  node_type = "cache.t1.micro"
  snapshot_retention_limit = 0
  consolidation = local.node_type == "cache.t1.micro" && local.snapshot_retention_limit > 0 ? false : true
}


module "validation" {
  source = "./module"
  
  node_type     = local.node_type
  consolidation = local.consolidation
}
```

After that inside module folder, you can evaluate individual variables like variable `node_type` or more complex validation like variable `consolidation`

```
variable "consolidation" {
    type = bool
    description = "consolidation of locals `node_type` & `snapshot_retention_limit` "
    validation {
        condition     = var.consolidation == true
        error_message = "Module parameter `consolidation` can not be equals `false`."
    }
}


variable "node_type" {
  description = "Required AWS values"
  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("^cache\\..*\\..*", var.node_type))
    error_message = "Only nodes starting with cache. are allowed."
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

as you cannot refer to other variables outside of the specific variable, you can do it in a different way with using it as a list:

```
variable "fet_code" {
  description = "Set the feature code"
  type        = list
  default     = ["test", ""]
  validation {
    condition     = var.fet_code[0] == "test" && length(var.fet_code[1]) != 3
    error_message = "The environment has been set to 'test' but the fet_code has not be defined."
  }
}
```