# Terraform: set variable default as null if another variable is x

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to write up some terraform code which will create a function and preferably create a new execution role, however the user does have the option of attaching an existing role.

```
variable "create_role" {
  description = "Controls whether IAM role for Lambda Function should be created"
  type        = bool
  default     = true
}

variable "lambda_role_arn" {
  description = " IAM role ARN attached to the Lambda Function. This governs both who / what can invoke your Lambda Function, as well as what resources our Lambda Function has access to. See Lambda Permission Model for more details."
  type        = string
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
    function_name                   = function_name
    role                            = var.create_role ? aws_iam_role.lambda[0].arn : var.lambda_role_arn
```

The drawback with this method is that there is a chance of create_role = false and lambda_role_arn being undefined.

If there a method of only allowing lambda_role_arn to be null IF create_role is true?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66682419/2442804 - there are only workarounds to get this to work...

Comment: Add a ```count = if var.create_role && var.lambda_role_arn != null ? 1 : 0``` to the lambda function so that it does not get created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to prevent the invalid situation from occurring in the first place by making a single variable which controls both of these behaviors together. This sort of design is also often easier for users of a module to understand, because they can see everything related to a particular behavior all in one place.

Based on your requirements, I would probably design this so that the module declares its own role only if the caller doesn't provide one:

```
variable "lambda_role_arn" {
  type    = string
  default = null

  description = "The ARN of a pre-existing role to use for the Lambda function. If unset, the module will declare a new role to use."
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  count = var.lambda_role_arn == null ? 1 : 0

  # ...
}

locals {
  # This is either the caller's provided ARN or
  # the ARN of the inline-declared role.
  final_role_arn = coalesce(
    var.lambda_role_arn,
    aws_iam_role.lambda[*].arn...
  )
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name = function_name
  role          = local.final_role_arn
  # ...
}
```

---

The idea of there being an automatic default behavior when an argument is left unset is a pretty common situation in Terraform -- lots of resource type arguments work like that, for example -- so a design like the above fits in with typical Terraform design idiom: either specify an explicit `lambda_role_arn` in the caller's `module` block, or omit it to get the default one.

However, in some situations that might be considered a little too "magical". For example, it might be true that for this particular module the *common case* is to pass in a role while having it automatically declared inline is the unusual case that must be explicitly selected. If that were true then I would choose a slightly different approach where the user of the module *must* specify how the role ARN is to be assigned, but can choose either option:

```
variable "lambda_role" {
  type = object({
    arn       = optional(string)
    automatic = optional(bool, false)
  })
  nullable = false

  validation {
    condition = (
      (var.lambda_role.arn != null && !var.automatic) ||
      (var.lambda_role.arn == null && var.automatic)
    )
    error_message = "Must set either the \"arn\" or \"automatic\" attribute, but not both."
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "lambda" {
  count = var.lambda_role.automatic ? 1 : 0

  # ...
}

locals {
  # This is either the caller's provided ARN or
  # the ARN of the inline-declared role.
  final_role_arn = coalesce(
    var.lambda_role.arn,
    aws_iam_role.lambda[*].arn...
  )
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda_function" {
  function_name = function_name
  role          = local.final_role_arn
  # ...
}
```

In this variation the caller of the module *must* choose between one of the two possible modes; omitting the argument altogether is invalid:

```
  lambda_role = {
    arn = "..."
  }
```

```
  lambda_role = {
    automatic = true
  }
```

(Side note: I called the boolean attribute "automatic" instead of "create" because it's a bit of a misnomer to say that the module "creates" the role. Instead, the module *declares* the role and then on the first `terraform apply` Terraform will plan to create it, but after that the role will already exist and so the module will just continue to manage it in whatever way needed to keep the remote object matching the changes to the configuration over time. Not a big deal if you *do* still want to call it `create`, but I find that tends to confuse some folks new to Terraform who aren't yet accustomed to its declarative programming model.)